# writing in a file array of structure

Tags: c, data-structures

I have C project.. I write a function called addBook, and it must to be array of structure.
I have a small problem which is writing in a file. I expect to have the user input inside the txt file, and the problem is that in txt file all what i get is numbers, idk where is the problem please check it out and let me know :)

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define MAX_Title 80
    #define MAX_Author 80
    #define MAX_Odata 80
    #define MAX_ISBN 11
    #define MIN_ISBN 9

//the following definitions will set a date limitation by checking the input date
     #define MAX_YEAR 2021
     #define MIN_YEAR 1600
     #define MAX_MONTH 12
     #define MIN_MONTH 1
     #define MAX_DAY 31
     #define MIN_DAY 1
     #define size 1000
     #define edSize 80

    typedef struct{

    int DD;
    int MM;
    int Year;
    }Datestr;

    typedef struct{

    char title[MAX_Title];
    char author[MAX_Author];
    int ISBN[MAX_ISBN];
    int Edition[edSize];
    Datestr date;
    }BOOK;


    void Add_Book(){

    int n;
    printf("How many input would you like to enter? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("storeNsort.txt","w");
        if(fptr == NULL){
            printf("Error opening the file!");
            exit(1);
        }

    BOOK *add;
    add = (BOOK *)calloc(n,sizeof(BOOK));
    if (add == NULL){
        printf("Error allocating the memory! ");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Fill the following data: \n");

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){

       printf("input Title: ");      fflush(stdin);   scanf("%s", add[i].title);
       printf("input Author: ");     fflush(stdin);   scanf("%s", add[i].author);
       printf("input ISBN: ");       fflush(stdin);   scanf("%d", &add[i].ISBN);
       printf("input Edition: ");    fflush(stdin);   scanf("%d", &add[i].Edition);
       printf("input DD/MM/YYYY: "); fflush(stdin);   scanf("%d%d%d", 
       &add[i].date.DD,&add[i].date.MM,&add[i].date.Year);

       fprintf(fptr,"%s%s%d%d%d%d%d",add[i].title,add[i].author,add[i].ISBN,add[i].Edition,
                              add[i].date.DD,add[i].date.MM,add[i].date.Year);
    }


    printf("\n");
    fclose(fptr);

    return;
    }
```

Comment: Consider making a [mcve] and providing one set of input and what the output you're seeing is. You might also add some error checking to make sure `scanf` isn't failing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an array for ISBN and Edition, try changing it to:

```
typedef struct {
  char title[MAX_Title];
  char author[MAX_Author];
  int ISBN;
  int Edition;
  Datestr date;
} BOOK;
```

This should work as long as the ISBN and Edition really are valid numbers or you could also just declare them as char arrays and read them as strings instead.